# Use Variable Date in Sed Command

Tags: sed, logs, split, data

I want to use `sed` command as below:

```
$ sed -n '/MONTH_TODAY DATE_YEST/,/MONTH_TODAY DATE_TODAY/p' \
   /home/crmiib/TESTUSERLOG/XYZ/user.log
```

I can print logs using:

```
$ sed -n '/Jul 27/,/Jul 28/p' /home/crmiib/TESTUSERLOG/XYZ/user.log
```

But I want to view logs using variables instead of hard coded dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes so the shell evaluates the variables before `sed` runs:

```
DATE_YEST="Jul 27"
DATE_TODAY="Jul 28"
sed -n "/$DATE_YEST/,/$DATE_TODAY/p" /home/crmiib/TESTUSERLOG/XYZ/user.log
```